# Database graph visualization

Tags: sqlite, data-visualization

I have a `sqlite3` database with table as `feature_category` :

```
feature|sentiment|count, example  
awesome|positive|1234
```

I want to to visualize this on a graph which could possible tell me clearly which word is more positive and which is not so positive

Could someone tell me any mapper/tool/technique of implementing this

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bar chart, with features listed alphabetically, and bar length and style indicating count and sentiment?

```
             average     +++++
             awesome     ++++++++++++++++++++
             bad         ---------
             good        +++++++++
             magnificent +++++++++++++++++++++++++++
             ok          +++
             terrible    ------------
```